# Número aleatorio pero evitando algunos

Tags: javascript

Quiero generar un número aleatorio, pero quiero evitar alguno en particular.

Por ejemplo, digamos que tengo este codigo:

```js
let numeroEvitado = 4;

console.log(parseInt(Math.random()*10));
```

¿Cómo evito el número 4?

Comment: Math.random es una función que no acepta parámetros y que devuelve un número de coma flotante en el rango [0, 1), así que en principio el 4 está evitado.

Comment: @javrd edite mi pregunta

Comment: en JS para obtener un random entero entre dos números `min` y `max` usar `Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min)`, luego un while haría el resto

Comment: Un comentario, las respuestas basadas en repetir el random hasta que no de un valor a excluir, son funcionales y practicas, y correctas en la mayoria de casos, pero matematicamente no es elegante, ya que no puedes demostrar que la funcion termine, dicho de otra manera, si la pregunta la encuentras en un examen de una carrera, es probable que ese tipo de respuesta resulte incorrecta. Lo ideal seria elegir entre un grupo de valores correctos.

Comment: @ArnauCastellví Si por "elegir entre un grupo de valores correctos" te refieres a cargar los valores correctos en un array y acceder por índice con un número aleatorio, esto solo es valido para grupos relativamente pequeños. Para grupos muy grandes, el cargar innecesariamente en memoria ese conjunto se aleja de lo ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer del siguiente modo:

```js
 var omitir = [1, 2, 3, 4]; //EL o los numeros que deseas omitir.
    var random = parseInt(getRandomArbitrary(1, 11));
    while (omitir.includes(random)){random = getRandomArbitrary(1, 11)}
    console.log(random);
    
// Retorna un número aleatorio entre min (incluido) y max (excluido)
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return parseInt(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}
```

**Edición:** En el apuro no me di cuenta que random retorna un número pseudo-aleatorio dentro del rango [0, 1). Por lo que agregue una función para agregarle un valor mínimo, máximo y de paso convertirlo a entero.

Espero que te sirva. Saludos!

Comment: Ver [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/206653/103383) para una solución óptima sin while.

Comment: Ninguna solucion con while es optima en ningun caso. puede que esta funcion nunca termine de ejecutarse.

Comment: @gbianchi En que esta solución no es optima, estoy de acuerdo, pero que "puede que esta funcion nunca termine de ejecutarse" es falso. Eso solo ocurriría, en este caso, si la lista de omitir incluyera el conjunto entero del 1 al 10. En general, si la lista de omitir incluye todo el rango de posibles números aleatorios [min, max). En otro caso, la probabilidad de que no acabe nunca es 0.

Comment: @javrd teoricamente, no se puede calcular la probabilidad, pero tene en cuenta que si el sistema estuviera sobrecargado, y la funcion que retorna aleatorios (que son pseudoaleatorios) siempre devolviera el mismo, que es el que no queremos, entonces esta funcion podria trabarse eternamente. Esto es teoria, en la practica en general tardan pero terminan.

Comment: @gbianchi teoricamente, la función nos devuelve números pseudoaleatorios todos con la misma probabilidad, ya que una buena función generadora de números aleatorios debe cumplir una distribución de probabilidad uniforme y continua. Por tanto, la probabilidad de que salga un elemento entre un número `X` de elementos es de `1/X`. La probabilidad de que salga `N` veces seguida ese elemento es de `1/X^N`. Cuando `N` tiende a infinito, este número tiende a 0. La probabilidad, calculada teóricamente, es 0.

Comment: No es una funcion aleatoria, y en general no tienen una buena distribucion, por eso no se usan para cosas importantes ;) @javrd

Comment: @gbianchi Sigo discrepando, aunque la distribución es solo aproximada, y por tanto la probabilidad `1/X^N` es aproximada, la tendencia a 0 se mantendría. Por muy mala que sea la distribución, no va a llegar un momento en el que nos de de forma continua y sin cambio posterior un valor. Si bien es verdad que, al final, la implementación depende del navegador, por lo que una mala implementación podría devolver un número constante. Pero creo que esa discusión escapa del ámbito del hilo. En cualquier caso, yo estoy completamente de acuerdo en que es mejor no usar una solución basada en while.

Answer (score 1):

Depende de lo que quieras, esto podría servirte o no. Te doy dos soluciones para dos supuestos distintos.

Partamos del supuesto de que solo quieres excluir un número, `c`, en un rango `[a, b]` de enteros que lo incluye. En este caso, puedes generar un número aleatorio entre `a` y `b-1`, y en el caso de que el número sea mayor o igual a `c`, sumarle 1. Lo bueno de esto es que siempre vas a conseguir en un solo intento un número en este rango excluyendo `c`.

```js
function randomExcluded(a, b, c) { 
    let n = Math.floor(Math.random() * (b-a) + a); 
    if (n >= c) n++; 
    return n; 
}

// Test
const r = {}
for (let i =0; i<1000; i+=1){
    const n = randomExcluded(1,10,4)
    r[n] = r[n] ? r[n]+1 : 1;
}
console.log(`Número: ocurrencias (aprox. ${Math.round(1000/9)})`)
console.log(r)
```

Generalicemos lo anterior partiendo ahora del supuesto de que quieres excluir en un rango `[a, b]` de enteros una lista de números contenidos en `L`, todos dentro del rango. En este caso, vamos a realizar la misma idea que antes, pero por reasignación en vez de sumar 1 a los que estén por encima del excluido. Generamos un número aleatorio en el rango `[a, b-L.length]`. Por cada uno de los valores contenidos en `L`, le vamos a asignar un valor de los que hemos quitado del rango, quedando así completo el rango. Si el número generado es uno de la lista, devolvemos su nueva asignación. Por ejemplo, podemos reasignar en función del lugar que ocupa el entero a excluir en la lista, de forma que para el que ocupa la posición 0, devolvemos `b`, para el que ocupa la posición 1, `b-1`, y así hasta llegar a `b-L.length+1`, último número que no hemos generado pero que estaba dentro del rango requerido. Para ello primero vamos a tener que preparar un objeto de reasignaciones, de forma que evitemos dar como valor de reasignacion un número que, aunque fuera del rango que queríamos por ser mayor que `b-L.length+1`, este en la lista de excluidos.

```js
function randomExcluded(a, b, L) {
    // Creación de lista de reasignación (numeros dentro del rango,
    // no excluidos, que no serán generados por random)
    const r = {}
    const bRest = []
    for (let i = 0; i<L.length; i+=1) {
        let n = b-i
        if (!L.includes(n)){
            bRest.push(n)
        }
    }
    // Creación de objeto de reasignación (mapa o diccionario entre
    // valores excluidos y su reasignación)
    for (let i = 0; i<L.length; i+=1) {
        if (L[i] <= b - L.length){
            r[L[i]] = bRest[i]
        }
    }
    var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * (b+1-L.length-a) + a); 
    if (L.includes(n)){
        n=r[n];
    }
    return n;      
}

// Test
const r = {}
for (let i =0; i<1000; i+=1){
    const n = randomExcluded(1,10,[2,4,6,8])
    r[n] = r[n] ? r[n]+1 : 1;
}
console.log(`Número: ocurrencias (aprox. ${Math.round(1000/6)})`)
console.log(r)
```

La función del primer supuesto tiene complejidad `O(1)`, sin embargo la del segundo supuesto, al tener que iterar sobre `L` e incluir la función `includes` (la cual vuelve a recorrer `L`) dentro del bucle, su complejidad de de `O(n²)` respecto a la longitud de `L`, pero ambas ejecutan la función `Math.random()` una sola vez. Son por lo tanto las óptimas, en lugar de una solución basada en bucle en la que la complejidad dependerá de la probabilidad de que el número devuelto este dentro de la lista de excluidos.

**Recuerda que Math.random no es criptográficamente seguro y no debe usarse por tanto para tal fin**

Comment: Así a ojo, creo que tu solucion proboca que ciertos valores tengan mas probabilidad de salir que otros, por ejemplo, usando rango 1-3 evitando el dos, el 1 tiene 1/3 y el 3 2/3.

Comment: Falso! Si quieres un rango 1-3 generas solo números del 1 al 2 (recordemos que la funcion random genera en [0, 1), el último valor esta excluido). Como quieres evitar el 2, si sale 1 devuelve 1, pero si sale dos, se reasigna a 3. Tanto el 1 como el 3 tienen 50% de probabilidad. En cambio en el supuesto del array si que hay un fallo en la reasignación de valores que voy a arreglar en cuanto tenga tiempo esta noche.

Comment: @ArnauCastellví olvide nombrarte. Ya está corregida también la función con array. Ambas funciones mantienen la homogeneidad de probabilidad entre todos los resultados, porque se obtiene un número aleatorio entre el número de elementos posibles (en tu ejemplo, entre 2 elementos, ya que hay 3 y uno excluido). ;)

Answer (score -2):

Tal vez puedas intentar haciendo este código:

```js
const except = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let random;
do {
  random = getRandom(1, 11)
} while (except.includes(random));

console.log(random);
    
function getRandom(min, max) {
  return parseInt(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}
```

Espero te sirva.